# Instantiating different class in constructor in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, constructor

I am very new to Java have just started working on simple example programs.

How can I create class A's instance inside class B's constructor. For example, I want to create an array of objects of class A , in class B's constuctor. The psudo code would look like

```
class B {

public static A myarray;
B (int number){
  myarray = new A [number];
}
```

Edited:

```
public class TestClassA {

    public static int []  ArrayA = new int [6];
    TestClassA () {
        for (int i=0; i < 6; i++){
            ArrayA[i]=i;
            System.out.print("TestClassA ");
        }
    }
}

public class TestClassB {

    public TestClassA [] A;
    TestClassB (int num) {
        A = new TestClassA[num];
    }
}

public class Exec {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        TestClassB B;
        B = new TestClassB(2);

    }
}
```

When I execute this, I don't see any messages as "TestClassA ". I expect it to create 2 instances of TestClassA array , hence I should see the TestClassA 12 times. Not sure where am I doing wrong.

Comment: `myarray` should not be static, but it should be an array. Other than that, your code is just fine.

Comment: myarray should be declared as an array :)

Comment: can you paste the code for same...

Comment: You need to initialize your `TestClassA[]` array just like you did your `int[]` ArrayA. I'd already covered this in my answer. Check updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of pointers

- Don't use `static`, unless you want to share the array of `A` objects with every instance of class `B`.
- You do however need to use `[]` while declaring the reference to indicate that it's an `Array`.
- Make your member fields `private` as well. Then control access to them through `public` or `protected` getter/setter methods.

Your code should look like

```
public class B {

    private A[] arrayOfAobjects;

    B (int number) {
         arrayOfAobjects = new A[number];
    }

    public A[] getArrayOfAobjects() {
        return arrayOfAobjects;
    }
}
```

***EDIT**: (to elaborate on @MikeStrobel's comments below)*
When you create an array, it gets initialized with default values as per the type of the `Array`.  For example, every array element is set to `0` for an `int []`, `0.0` for a `double []`, `null` for all types of `Object []` object arrays.

```
new int[100]; // creates an Array with 100 zeroes
new A[number]; // creates an Array of size "number"
               // but filled with nulls (instead of A objects)
```

So, you need to populate the arrays with correct values yourself. In your case, something like

```
B (int number) {
     arrayOfAobjects = new A[number];
     for (int i=0; i < number; i++) {
         arrayOfAobjects[i] = new A(); // initialize the A[] array
     }
}
```

***EDIT 2** :*

```
public class TestClassB {

    public TestClassA [] A;

    TestClassB (int num) {
        A = new TestClassA[num];
        for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
            A[i] = new TestClassA(); // You need to INITIALIZE your Array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting, since the OP is new to Java, that the allocated array will be filled with `null` pointers.  Maybe add an initialization loop to your example?

Answer (score 1):

If you **want to create an object of class A inside the constructor of class B** you can simply do it like this:

```
class B { 
    public A object;
    B (int number){
      object= new A();
    }

class A{

    }
```

If you want to **create an array of A class** then do not make the variable as static.

```
class B { 
        public A[] myarray;
        int number = 5;
        B (int number){
          myArray = new A[number];
        }

class A{

        }
```

**EDIT:** Syntax of array of objects(You need array of 4 objects).

```
 A[] a = new A[4]; // Create the array of size 4.
 A a1 = new A(); //Create an object
 ............    //Similarly create other three objects
 a[0] = a1; //Add the object to the array
 ............   //Similarly add other three objects
```

Comment: What is the systax to get array of class. sorry for dump questions

Comment: I am able to get the array but, some how it is not hitting the constructor of Class A when I instantiate it as Array. I works fine in simple instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class B {

public A[] myarray;
B (int number){
  myarray = new A [number];
}
```

it would be good to practice to use instance variables in private or protected mode, and using getter and setter methods to access it. This code will just create a un-initialized array of `A` objects only. If you want to use those, you need to init them seperately like `myarra[i]=new A();` where `i` being any number `0<=i<number`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should be writing.

```
class B{
public A[] myArray;

B(int number){
  myArray = new A[number];
   }
  }
```

Comment: `class` should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class B {

  private A[] arrayOfAs;

  public B (int number) {
     this.arrayOfAs = new A[number];
  }

  public getAs() {
     return this.arrayOfAs;
  }
}
```

Not above that `arrayofAs` is *not* static, because you don't want to share your array among all instances of `B`. I also made it *private* because that is considered good practice for instance variables.

You can return this array to a different class using the `getAs()` accessor method above.